# X-Ray is too much X-Ray

Tags: customization

When I use X-Ray, the mesh also becomes transparent which is often super confusing.

[image]

What I want is to see all the vertices/edges just like in the picture, the closest ones are more visible than the "hidden" ones, but I want the mesh to not be transparent.

I think it is really confusing to see the shape of the mesh in the X-Ray because it has no depth at all. Ideally, it should look like a frosted glass material

Is there a way?

Answer (score 5):

just open the setting in shading and set the x-ray value to 1 that means it is fully visible but keep the edges and vertices see throu. The lower the number is the more transparent the geometry is.
[image]

Comment: Thankyou that was exactly what i needed!!!

Comment: @ErikW if this answer provided you with the solution to your question, you should consider [accepting the answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)